# How can I use setState to save current location in react native?

Tags: react-native

I use this code to get current location from user, but now I have a notice when I use setState to save latitude and longitude to states.

> ReferenceError: setState is not defined

```
 async componentDidMount(){
     const { status } = await Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.LOCATION);
       if (status === 'granted') {
           const location = await Expo.Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
             enableHighAccuracy: true,
           });
           setState({
             lat:JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude),
             long:JSON.stringify(location.coords.longitude),
           });
       }
 }
```

How can I save location to states?

Comment: because when you componentDidMount state not exist, use variable  like to this.lat and this.long in your constructor, and set it in

Comment: use this.setState.... instead of only setState()..... if you have defined state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setState with `this`.

in your `constructor` add state variables,

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...
            lat: 0.000,
            long: 0.000,
            ...
        };
    }
```

Then add `this` to method.

```
async componentDidMount(){
     const { status } = await Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.LOCATION);
       if (status === 'granted') {
           const location = await Expo.Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
             enableHighAccuracy: true,
           });
           this.setState({
             lat:JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude),
             long:JSON.stringify(location.coords.longitude),
           });
       }
 }
```